# latex error unicode character u+202a in \maketitle

Tags: errors, titles, overleaf, unicode

At the line where I make title (\maketitle) in latex, I get the error "Latex Error: Unicode character (U+202a)". I know that there is an invisible LEFT TO RIGHT character but how can I find it and where should I search? The error happens at the below part of the file:

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
```

Comment: What is your full code? Do not post code snippets because they are unserviceable in some cases.

Comment: Declare the character with some visible output https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286513/2388